# Convert European date to UNIX while factoring in timezone and summer time?

Tags: php, date, unix

I have dates in the following format for a set of past events:

```
year-m-day hour:second

e.g. 2014-05-25 20:41
```

These dates are based on Brussels time (GMT + 1hr + (1hr summer time)).

I am attempting to calculate how much time has passed since an event started by taking this date/time and minusing it from current date/time as follows:

```
$current_time = time();
$event_time = date('2014-05-25 20:41');

echo ($current_time - $event_time)
```

However, due to the timezone, the date is two hours ahead of Unix time.

Is there a simple way to accurately convert from Brussels summer time to Unix bearing in mind summer time kicks in each year on a different date?

Comment: Did you tried setting timezone in php and using http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set time zone and use [DateTime::diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function and [DateInterval::format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
$dateNow = new DateTime();
$dateBefore = new DateTime('2014-05-25 20:41') ;
$interval = $dateNow->diff($dateBefore);
echo $interval->format('%h hours %i min ago') . PHP_EOL;
```

Which shows:

```
0 hours 37 min ago
```

And to just convert date to unix time [DateTime::format('U')](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) or [DateTime::getTimestamp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) like that:

```
echo $dateNow->format('U') . PHP_EOL
echo $dateNow->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But format('%U') returns '%U'

Comment: Corrected, there shouldn't be `%`. See my answer

Comment: I just get 'U' returned

Comment: `$now = new DateTime(); var_dump($now->format('U'));` returns `string(10) "1401046979"`

Comment: $dateNow->format('U') returns a unix time, but $interval->format('U') returns 'U'

Comment: Did you read manual for `DateTimeInterval::format()`? Unix timestamp is number of seconds from start of epoch so why don't you use `format()` to show you number of seconds?